# Detect number of global thresholds analyzing an image

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

I'm working on implementing an algorithm to find multiple global threshold values of an image by analyzing histogram with math-lab. I find it would be easy if I could find number of thresholds at the beginning.

[image]

For an example I want to detect that histogram (a) has 1 threshold and histogram (b) has 2 thresholds.

Any idea on how to do this?

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 1):

I think it might help you if you can detect the modes of the histogram. You'll find mean-shift clustering useful for this purpose. I don't know if that's available in Matlab though. Once you find these modes and sort them, your threshold values should lie in-between two consecutive modes.

Comment: Looks like your data is a combination of gaussians.  Perhaps this can help: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/gmdistribution-class.html

Comment: A very popular mean shift implementation can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/10161-mean-shift-clustering